# Get correct index of selected word - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, selection

I have a React application which displays a text like:

```html
<div>
    <span>The cat is on the</span> <span>table</span> and it <span>is</span> sleeping
</div>
```

I want to select **"is sleeping"** and get its start/end index referred to the whole text.

I know there is **getSelected()** Javascript function but this function returns indexes referred to parent node. Considering the above example, the start index is 0 (referred to node **"is"**) and the end index is 9 (referred to node **" sleeping"**).

How can i get the correct indexes?

Comment: Does this one solve your issue? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/MWYJoYK

Comment: Unfortunately no. 
The result expected selecting "is sleeping" is:
startIndex: 31
endIndex: 42

The result expected selecting the second "is":
startIndex: 31
endIndex: 33

Answer (score 0):

Store the text in a variable then run the `indexOf()` function to it

Maybe this link will help [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: indexOf doesn't work if a word occurs multiple times